# Ideal Polling Mechanism/Interval for Android client/server application

Tags: android

I am planning to implement a chat application in Android, and need to make a few design decisions related to polling the server for updates:

1. How often should I poll for new messages? Will polling every minute be a good choice?
2. How can real time chat be supported? Should the polling be done every 5 seconds in case the user sends message and then return to long polling interval in case no new message is received?

I also need to make sure the application does not drain the battery quickly. I need to design the application on similar lines as WhatsApp. I am not sure how does it manage polling, but I know its not a battery killer.

Comment: Have you considered XMPP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/).

WhatsApp uses a modified version of XMPP.

Here's a [tutorial](http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample) to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Polling is not the answer for this type of application. If your application is solely Android base you should look at the Google Cloud Messaging Framework (http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).

This allows you to push messages to individual clients over xmpp (or http ping to pull). This way they can get updates almost instantly.

Answer (score 0):

For the chat I'd make two different kind of polling. 
First if the application is in background (every minute or something like this) and if the app is started every second or maybe long polling: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling

Answer (score 0):

1. For avoiding to be a battery killer, you should stop the loop for polling when screen off, or make the interval to be very long when screen off
2. Maybe you can keep a long lived connection to make a real time chat.
3. Using [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) is a better choice